# Have Spring MVC app not assume root context

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc

I had to take an existing app, using Spring MVC 3.1.0, which assumes in many places what the root context name is.  I'm changing the root context name, but I really don't want to hardcode the root context, I'd like the app to just work.  Obviously, I'll still have to change those references, but I'd like it to just work if I later change the root context again.

The references are in a few different kinds of locations:

- One controller method that does '`return new ModelAndView("redirect:/OriginalAppName/home");`'
- References in css files like "`background: url(/OriginalAppName/resources/images/chng-pwd-backg.png)`"
- Inline javascript code like "...action="/OriginalAppName/account"
- anchors like '`<a href="/OriginalAppName/home" ...`'

What are reasonable strategies for addressing this?

Comment: AFAIK, redirect views are processed as relative path (to container). For web-part (css/js/html), we solve the problem by using ONLY relative links anywhere.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Are you saying that all of these references will work perfectly fine if "/OriginalAppName" is removed from all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question consists of 3 parts:

**1.** Concerning `redirect:` view name prefix, [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) says:

> A logical view name such as redirect:/myapp/some/resource will redirect relative to the current Servlet context

So, view name `"redirect:/home"` for your case should work correctly.

**2.** static web resources (JS/CSS) for portability should use relative links anywhere:

```
background: url(./resources/images/chng-pwd-backg.png)
```

or even maybe:

```
background: url(../resources/images/chng-pwd-backg.png)
```

depending on containing page URL.

**3.** dynamic web resources (HTML/JSP, etc), may use the same way as for static resources:

```
<a href="./home" ...
```

or may use built-in [`<spring:url>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring.tld.url) tag:

```
<a href='<spring:url url="/home">' ...
```

or [`<c:url>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) tag:

```
<a href='<c:url value="/home">' ...
```